# Why is the program not throwing a run time error?

Tags: runtime-error, c++98

This program fills a vector beyond its last index (Line II). I would have expected a run time error to be thrown. But the result I get is `1, 1, 1, 8, 7, 7, 7,`.

Can someone explain why that happens?
I tried to use different flags like `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-Wpedantic` but the result remains the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
void printer(int i) {
        cout << i << ", ";
}
int main() {
        vector<int> v1(7,1);
        fill(v1.begin()+3, v1.end()-1, 8);//LINE I
        fill_n(v1.begin()+4, 5, 7);//LINE II
        for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), printer);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The result is *undefined behavior*, which may or may not result in a run-time error. It could also result in your machine exploding, or *another* machine exploding, or François Hollande being elected President of the United States.

Comment: Made me laugh. So this program is not suitable at all for an assessment I think. The options were "compilation error on Line I", "compilation error on Line II", "run time error on Line I", "run time error on Line II" and the numbers printed as per question. I understand well UB means it's unpredictable.